# tableView reloads but does not update/change UI

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a tableView with a custom cell. In that custom cell I have two `uiview` stacked horizontally.1st view displays Product Details, 2nd view displays it's Availability. I am hiding 2nd view initially and displaying it only when the product is **OUT OF STOCK**.

Data in the 1st view is loaded dynamically after login. In the response of first api, I am calling 2nd view's api for every indexpath in tableView, to hide/show 2nd view. 
I have a sidebar menu, from where I select product categories like 'Clothes', 'Electronics', 'All'  etc. By default 'All' is loaded after login. So when I select 'Clothes', then api is called to load clothes details in 1st view and it's availability(if OUT OF STOCK) in 2nd.

The issue is when I select product type and reload tableView, then product details are shown correctly, but OUT OF STOCK details are shown incorrectly. The 2nd view should be visible only and only when the product is not available. Even after refreshing the tableView it shows wrong data in the UI. I am getting correct values in JSON response, but they do not reflect in tableView. I am using same tableView, but reloading the data when user selects any product. 2nd View should be expanded only and only when the product is OUT OF STOCK, else user sees only the 1st View i.e product details. I am messing up with the UI, please help me with this, I am struggling since a week.

```
public static var productListArray = [Products]()
public static var productAvailableArray = [AvailableProduct]()
public static var availableIdArray = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       

    //Pull Down to refresh 
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshAction), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

    getProductList(request: productListRequest)
    getProductAvailability(request: availabilityRequest)

    // Notify tableView to reload data from another VC
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTableview(_:)), name: .reload, object: nil)
}

@objc func reloadTableview(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@objc func refreshAction(){  
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    getProductList(request: productListRequest)
    Home.productAvailableArray.removeAll()     // to append new objects for respective product
    getProductAvailability(request: availabilityRequest)
}

public func getProductList(request : ProductRequest) {
        User.apiProductList(Request: request) {(response, error) in
                let array = (response.obj as? [Products])!
                if array.count == 0{
                    print("No Products…\n")
                } else {
                    Home.productListArray = array
                    if response.isSuccess() {
                            for id in array {
                                Home.availabilityArray.removeAll()
                                Home.availableIdArray.removeAll()
                                self.getProductAvailability(request: availabilityRequest)
                                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)
                           }                           
                        }
                }               
                }       
        }

public func getProductAvailability(request : AvailableProductRequest) {
            User.apiProductAvailability(Request:request, callback: {(response, error) in                
                    let object = response.obj as! AvailableProduct                     
                    if response.obj != nil {
                        Home. availableIdArray.append(object.productId! as! Int)
                        Home.productAvailableArray.append(object)
                     }                
                })
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reload, object: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “productcell”, for: indexPath) as! ProductViewCell
    let data = Home.productListArray[indexPath.row]

    //------------ show/hide available product view for each table row in home screen ----------------------
        for productId in Home.availableIdArray{             
            if data.productId == 0 {
                cell.availableProductView.isHidden = true
                expandedRows.remove(indexPath)
            }else{                  
                if data.productId == productId {
                    cell.availableProductView.isHidden = false
                    expandedRows.insert(indexPath)                       
                }else{
                    expandedRows.remove(indexPath)                      
                }
            }
        }
    }        
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just an advice, try to move logic out of the VC, and avoid that public static vars you are using really bad practices and you will have unexpected behaviors with that architecture, check MVVM, MVP :). And try to make everything you can private

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez I am reloading tableView from another VC. I did not use static var initially, but since my array would not reload with new api response object so I made them static. What can I do? if not global?

Comment: If you are setting the values from another VC you have to create a setter in the VC that receives the data like func setData(YourNewData), and at the end of the set tableView.reloadData(), so each time you set the data the VC will reload himself, and never use static, you can use self.productList to access to the variable

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez thankyou! I will try by using setter.